# Why do you say "un jean" for jeans in French?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, habillement

Title. Would it not be *les jeans* or *des jeans*? Does it mean a pair of jeans?

Comment: Because it is a lot more logical to speak about one unity with singular ?

Comment: Compare *pants*. English, German, Spanish, Italian, and Portuguese all have a plural word for "pants", but French speaks of *un pantalon*. I suppose that conceptually, whereas many languages consider it two pant legs, in French it's a single article of clothing. This is potentially worth looking into in case there's an interesting reason why this happened (though one must be prepared to conclude that it's arbitrary)...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Though "un pantalon" is used, "une **paire** de pantalon" or simply "des pantalons" are by far the most common ways to refer to the article of clothing, at least in my family and my community.

Comment: @Feelew I wonder if that's regional. What say you about *un jean* ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It would sound strange to me, though not necessarily unFrench. More like I would think the person using it would be from far far away from my place.

Comment: @LukeSawczak An interesting read in LBU, about the words where singular and plural are competing. Any piece of clothing covering the bottom part of the body (where the 2 legs are the most important part of the article) used to be referred to in the plural, but singular is more common today, though several examples of plural by recent good authors are cited. The old fashion way seem to survive more vividly here in Quebec, where even **bobettes** (underwears), that do not cover the legs, are plural for just one piece.

Comment: @Feelew Merci, c'est intéressant. I notice [on Ngrams](http://ow.ly/bv0K30esYOR) that *un pantalon* is indeed outpacing the plural, and fast! And the *les* vote must even be inflated since it could just be more than one *pantalon*...

Comment: @Feelew Very interesting to hear differing usages. To add another regional testimony, I (north-east France) never heard *une paire de pantalons/jeans* or even *des pantalons/jeans* to refer to a single piece of leg clothing, not once. Always singular here, no exceptions at all.

Comment: @LukeSawczak German is like French, both are used, sing. and plur. (Duden: *haüifig auch in Plural mit singularischer Bedienung*) and [this thread on wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hose-vs-hosen.581445/) and on German SE the answers to [When do we use “Hose” like a plurale tantum?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3980/4737).

Comment: @Laure Oh ! Merci ...WordReference's [search](http://www.wordreference.com/ende/pants) is not to be taken on too much faith, then.

Comment: Why do you say shirt instead of a pair of sleeves? Car instead of four wheels? These things are somewhat arbitrary, perhaps based on some historical reality of two separate pants and a distinct codpiece. I've always found the likes of jeans, pants, and scissors quite illogical because they're only one item. For that matter, many (Chicagoland) Americans I know actually say *scissor*. In contrast to pants, socks are plural because they're two separate items. Incidentally, in Belgian-Dutch it's one *jeans*, two *jeans*. (In Netherlandic-Dutch it's one *spijkerbroek*, two *spijkerbroeken*.)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Dans *Zazie dans le métro:* «je te jure que c’est hà moi les bloudjinnzes 72».

Answer (score 8):

Both are used *un jean* or *des jeans* where one means a single pair of jeans. People will say *un jean* where they say *un pantalon* for a pair of trousers. We can add *culotte* and *short* to the *list*.

**In France** people mostly use these words in the singular when talking about a single piece of clothing and it is how dictionaries say the word is used nowadays, the plural for a single piece of clothing is noted as outdated in writing, but it was still used in the plural in writing until the early 20th c. as either *pantalons* or *une paire de pantalons*.

> C’est un gaillard qui en dégoise ; il porte une barbe longue d’une aune, **des pantalons collants**, un habit à larges revers, et un bolivar sur la tête,... (Alfred de Musset, *Lettres de Dupuis et Cotonet au directeur de la Revue des Deux-Mondes*, 1836).

Some people still use the plural form for a single piece of clothing in the **south of France**, because of the influence of Occitan where the plural is used for a single pair of trousers.

Concerning **Québec** we find this testimony from a [Quebecer](http://www.linguatechediteur.com/auplaisirdesmots/ipantalonsi-iculottesi-et-ijeansi-pluriels-enigmatiques):

> Au Québec et au Canada français, comme il arrive souvent, les usages anciens ont mieux résisté à l'érosion du temps. Même si l'expression paire de pantalons a pris de la bouteille - je l'utilisais couramment dans ma lointaine jeunesse -, le pluriel pantalons désignant un seul vêtement reste encore d'usage courant. Le mot culottes, pour sa part, est demeuré très fréquent tant avec paire que sans. (*Pantalons, culottes et jeans : pluriels énigmatiques*)

According to the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pantalons) In **Belgium** and in **Switzerland** the plural can still be heard.

*Pantalon* is a rather recent word (17th c.) derived from the name of [the character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantalone) in *commedia dell'arte*. We can presume the singular established itself in the end because of the proper name, but as well because what used to be a two part piece of clothing is now seen as one single piece. Before *pantalon* appeared French used words in the plural to designate a piece of clothing that covered entirely or partially both legs at the same time : [braies](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braies_(v%C3%AAtement)) (from Latin [*braca*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/braca#la) for one trouser leg), [chausses](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chausse) and [caleçon](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cale%C3%A7on) both deriving from Latin [calceus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chausse#.C3.89tymologie) that also gave *chaussure* and *chausson*.

Plural to singular can also been explained by the change in fashions. Here an extract from a thread on [Projet Babel](http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1905) that of course would need to be substantiated by historians but that I am inclined  to believe:

> J'ai aussi entendu indistinctement des pantalons, une paire de pantalons, ou un pantalon.
>   Il se trouve que les pantalons des dames étaient faits de deux jambes rigoureusement indépendantes l'une de l'autre : seule les solidarisait la coulisse de la taille. Ce dispositif permettait de communier avec la nature sans avoir à baisser le dit pantalon, dont il fallait retrouver la coulisse sous trois épaisseurs de jupon...
>   Les danseuses de cancan avaient ordre de coudre l'entrejambe de leur pantalon, et les spectateurs, bien entendu, n'attendaient qu'une chose : que la couture craque...
>
> A la même époque, les culottes des petits garçons n'étaient pas non plus cousues, pour le même motif : leur permettre de se soulager sans avoir à se battre avec les boutons. Il arrivait qu'un pan de chemise passe par la fente : observez attentivement les gravures qui illustrent les œuvres de la comtesse de Ségur, vous verrez ce pan de chemise des petits bonshommes de trois quatre ans...
>
> Donc, deux jambes indépendantes font une paire de pantalons, mais maintenant que tous les pantalons ont un fond solide, il n'existe plus que le pantalon singulier.

To be read also: [De singuliers pluriels](http://correspo.ccdmd.qc.ca/index.php/document/changement-et-continuite/de-singuliers-pluriels/).

Comment: Have you found data to back the statement "it was mostly used in the plural until the early 20th"? Google Ngram seems to disagree.

Comment: @jlliagre  I would no know how to find examples distinguishing between singular and plural use that would be significant with an ngram. But I know all the people around me used it in the plural in the second half of the 20th century. And some still do nowadays (and I can provide written examples). Use is one thing, dictionaries are another. The TLF says "Pantalon s'emploie gén. au sing. (sauf au Canada, où il est gén. au plur.), mais on rencontre dans des emplois vieillis: une paire de pantalons, des pantalons."

Comment: I updated my answer to show how Google Ngram might be used to compare singular and plural usage of similar words. I do not question the fact it was and might still be used in plural somewhere in France, but I disagree about "it was **mostly** used in plural until the early 20th" which is clearly not supported by Ngram statistics. There is simply no single year since the word is known when *pantalons* was more written than *pantalon*.

Answer (score 5):

*[Pantalon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pantalon)* obsoleted *[chausses](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chausses/2)* around the French revolution. *Chausses* (which gave the modern *chaussettes* - socks) itself obsoleted *[braies](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/braies)* (related to the *braguette* - trouser fly). Both *braies* and *chausses* were used in plural when naming the two legs garment.

When *pantalon* was introduced, from the *Commedia dell'arte* character's [Pantalone/Pantaloon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantalone) who was wearing red pants, plural and singular were competing for a while but the singular seems to have won in the 19th century, probably because *pantalon* dual nature was lost or rejected.

Here is an excerpt from the *[Nouvelle orthologie française](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Nouvelle_orthologie_fran%C3%A7aise.html?id=eAlFbBYNW_8C&redir_esc=y)*, 1832:
   
            [image]

The plural (*une paire de pantalons*) survived as a regionalism in Belgium and Switzerland and even more in Canada where it seems to be still the norm but has almost disappeared entirely in France although it might survive with elderly people in Southern France, Brittany and other regions.

A Ngram comparison of the percentage of singular vs total occurrences of a sample of words clearly shows *pantalon* follows almost the same usage pattern than *chemise* since at least 1880 so is clearly not in the same group than dual words like *gants*, *ciseaux* or *chaussettes*. Of course this is only based on books scanned by Google so might not perfectly reflect the spoken French reality, as Laure's personal experience might suggest.

[image] 
It is worth noting that this competition between singular and plural exists in Italy where *un paio di pantaloni* ("a pair of"+plural) is the traditional and widespread name, but *un pantalone* (singular) is often used in shops.

In France, *jean* is following the same pattern than *pantalon* so is always used as a singular (*un*) although sometimes the final s is kept (*un jeans*).

There is the same difference with short (French: *un short*, English: a pair of shorts).

Several similar "dual objects" are named using the plural in French, e.g.: *ciseaux*, *bretelles*, *lunettes*, *jumelles*…

The dual nature of these words is not questionable because they are made of two parts which have a individual name (un ciseau, une bretelle, une lunette …)  while *pantalon* (from a single person name) or *jeans* (from a town's name) are not etymologically components to be assembled in pairs.

Almost the opposite happened with "pin" which was adopted in French as *un pin's*.

Comment: Interesting your comment about the shops in Italy. While most Quebecers use the plural *(des pantalons)*, it seems to me like the style and fashion experts could easily talk about how *le pantalon* is worn this season, without sounding misplaced or foreigners. Perhaps we would still expect a plural from them when they refer to their own pair, though.

Comment: If it has "disappeared" entirely in France it must be very recent. It was still used (I was by no means an exception) in the second half of the 20th c. in the south west of France where I used to live.   *Les Bagarres du Petit Nicolas* 2006 : "Oui, papa, j'ai dit. Retrousse tes pantalons, tu seras rigolo comme tous les comiques qu'on voit au cinéma, dis, papa !"  And it's clear form the context he's talking about the pair of trousers his dad's wearing.

Answer (score 5):

L'usage peut varier selon les régions et le temps, comme on en discute ailleurs. On peut cependant noter simplement que :

> De nombreux noms qui désignent un objet composé de deux parties
>   identiques peuvent être employés tant au singulier qu'au pluriel. Dans
>   un cas, on considère l'objet ou le concept en soi; dans l'autre, on
>   considère les deux parties qui le composent.
>
> [ Banque de dépannage linguistique (Québec), [*Noms pouvant être
>   employés au singulier et au pluriel*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=jeans&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=3761) ]

Si on utilisait [indifféremment](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2073840) (contra [Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/jean/44840/difficulte)) [*jean*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jean) et *jeans* (de [*blue-jeans*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/blue-jean)), l'emploi au singulier pourrait servir à marquer davantage l'objet dans son entier par opposition à ses parties constituantes qui sont identiques. Ce serait une manière d'expliquer un tel choix si l'on veut s'en donner un. Ainsi *mon jean neuf*, *mon jeans neuf* et *mes jeans neufs* pourraient tous signifier un seul *jean(s)*, mais différemment. Le contexte et d'autres [noms](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26843/why-do-you-say-un-jean-for-jeans-in-french#comment54609_26843) etc. peuvent servir à préciser s'il s'agit d'un seul ou de plusieurs objets.

Answer (score 1):

In French, a single piece of clothe is singular.

For instance a sweater would be *un pull over* or *un sweat*. Shorts would be *un short*, and pants/trousers would be *un pantalon*.

*Un jean* being one specific kind of *pantalon*, would be singular too.

Comment: This is not the case in Quebec.

Comment: @ApplePie It is not the case either in some parts of France. I didn't know the word could be used in the singular until I went to school (south west of France), and then I still used it orally in the plural.

Comment: -1  It should say in the  answer that it expresses  a personal opinion and not a reality of the language.